# Deleting date column observations having certain format

Tags: sas

I am trying to delete all date columns `BRTHDTC DMDTC RFENDTC RFSTDTC` observations from DM dataset which is in my user defined library having `YYMMDD10. format`.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct catx(".",libname,memname), name into :dtelist separated by " ", :dtevars separated by " "
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname = upcase("Dtelib") and format =('YYMMDD10.');
quit;

data drpdte(Keep=&dtevars);
set &dtelist;
if &dtevars =('&dtevars'd,YYMMDD10.) then delete;
run;
```

but it returns an error of multiple arguments, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The DELETE statement will eliminate observations, not variables.  Did you mean to generate a DROP statement instead?

Comment: @Tom i want to drop whichever column has yymmdd10. format i want to drop that column from my data. in my case these columns `BRTHDTC DMDTC RFENDTC RFSTDTC`should be dropped from my ds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work for you. I output the `proc contents` and then string together the format variables so you then have a list of all variables and their formats. Then you can just put this into a macro and use it in a drop statement:

```
** test data **;
data test;
    bad_date = "05OCT2016"D;
    good_date = "12DEC2016"D;
    good_date1 = "22DEC2016"D;
    car = "Ford";
    model = "F-150";
    format bad_date yymmdd10. good_date yymmdd9. good_date1 date10.;
run;

** view list of variables and their formats **;
proc contents data = test noprint out=names; run;

** string together format and length to view YYMMDD10 **;
data names1; set names;
    new_format = compress(catx("",format,formatl));
    keep name new_format;
run;

** put the YYMMDD10 vars into a macro variable **;
proc sql noprint;
    select name
    into: dropvars separated by " "
    from names1
    where new_format = "YYMMDD10";
quit;

%put &dropvars.;

data test1; set test (drop=&dropvars.); run;
```